# Approximation of $ \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} e^{-x t} \sin (a x^{1/2})dx$ -- rapidly oscillating

Tags: integration, approximation

The exact solution of the integral
$$ I(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} e^{-x t} \sin (a x^{1/2})dx$$
according to mathematica is $$ \frac{a \sqrt{t}-\left(a^2-2 t\right) F\left(\frac{a}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)}{2 t^{5/2}}.$$
At large $t$ this result is dominated by the slowest-to-decay term: $I(t) \sim t^{-2}$.

Is there a means by which I can derive this asymptotic result directly? Is it also possible to access the $t \rightarrow 0$ form approximately? This is a rapidly oscillating integral, so I believe the method of stationary phase should be applicable. I know the critical points of the oscillating term are at
$$ x = \Big(\frac{\pi}{2a}\Big)^2(2n+1)^2,$$
where $n$ is a positive integer, so I guess I can write the integrand as a sum of the integrand expanded around these critical points, as in something like
$$ I(t) \approx  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-)^n \int_0^\infty dx \exp[a + b(x-x_n) + c (x-x_n)^2], $$
but I am unsure how to achieve this. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Hint for the large $t$ asymptotics: Watson's lemma. Btw, is $F$ the Dawson integral?

Comment: Take care : for large values of $t$, we have
$$I(t)=\frac{a}{t^\color{red}{2}}\Bigg[1-\frac{a^2}{3 t}+\frac{a^4}{20 t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comment: The other commenters have provided asymptotic expressions. What are you looking for that they have not given? If it’s about workings, then I can provide you with a direct derivation of $I(t)\sim\frac{a}{t^2},\,t\to\infty$ if you wish

Comment: Workings are what I'm after @FShrike! Asymptotics are easy enough with mathematica - I'd like to have a means to pick off the $t \rightarrow \infty$ behavior without using a computer

Comment: @kevinkayaks As I said, use [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: @Gary There has to be a typo somewhere. If we take $x = (u/t)^2$ and deform the contour to $\gamma = [0, i \epsilon, \infty + i \epsilon)$, we get
$$I(t) = \operatorname {Im} \frac 2 {t^3} \int_\gamma
 u^2 e^{(i a u - u^2)/t} du =
\operatorname {Im} \frac 2 {t^3} \int_{[0, i \infty)}
 u^2 e^{i a u/t} du + o(1)$$
for $t \to 0^+$, so $I(0^+)$ exists and is finite.

Comment: @Maxim My calculation below shows that $I(t)$ has an essential singularity at $t=0$. You can also use the Maclaurin series of $F$ and the explicit formula for $I$ to demonstrate it.

Comment: @Gary There may exist a finite one-sided limit at an essential singularity, no contradiction there. My claim is that $a/(2 t^2) - e^{a^2/(4 t)} (a/t^2 + 8/a^3 + O(t))$ cannot be correct for $t \to 0^+$, because that does contradict the existence of a finite limit. The Laurent series for $I(t)$ in your answer is correct, but $I(0^+)$ cannot be obtained by interchanging the sum and the limit.

Comment: @Maxim You are right, I made a mistake. The correct formula is $$
I(t) =  - \frac{4}{{a^3 }} - \frac{{48}}{{a^5 }}t + \mathcal{O}(t^2 )
$$ as $t\to 0^+$, $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Did any of us answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the power series expansion of the sine function,
$$
x^{1/2} \sin (ax^{1/2} ) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{a^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}x^{n + 1} } 
$$
for any $x\geq 0$. Substitution into the integral and integrating term-by-term gives
$$
I(t) = \frac{a}{{t^2 }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{(n + 1)!}}{{(2n + 1)!}}\left( {\frac{{a^2 }}{t}} \right)^n } .
$$
This series converges for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$ since
$$
\frac{{(n + 1)!}}{{(2n + 1)!}} \sim \frac{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}{{2^{2n + 1} n!}},\quad n\to +\infty.
$$
To justify the term-wise integration, one can use the fact that the absolute value of the remainder in the series for the sine is at most the absolute value of the first omitted term.

Note that the series in fact converges for all $t\in \mathbb C \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$, and $I(t)$ has an essential singularity at $t=0$ (if $a\neq 0$).

**Addendum.** Elaboration on what I said about the justification of interchanging the order of summation and integration. Using the known properties of the Maclaurin series of the sine, we have, for any $N\geq 0$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$,
$$
x^{1/2} \sin (ax^{1/2} ) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^n \frac{{a^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}x^{n + 1} }  + ( - 1)^N \frac{{a^{2N + 1} }}{{(2N + 1)!}}x^{N + 1} \theta _N (x,a)
$$
with a suitable $0 < \theta _N (x,a) < 1$. Thus, employing the mean value theorem for improper integrals, we find, for any $N\geq 0$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$,
$$
I(t) = \frac{a}{{t^2 }}\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^n \frac{{(n + 1)!}}{{(2n + 1)!}}\left( {\frac{{a^2 }}{t}} \right)^n }  + ( - 1)^N \frac{{(N + 1)!}}{{(2N + 1)!}}\left( {\frac{{a^2 }}{t}} \right)^N \Theta _N (t,a)} \right)
$$
with an appropriate $0 < \Theta _N (t,a) < 1$. Letting $N\to +\infty$ and applying the above estimate for the ratio of factorials yields the desired series expansion.

Comment: The way it's written, the justification for the termwise integration is not quite clear (we can interchange the sum and the integral in $\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n x^{2 n + 1}/(2 n + 1)! \, dx$ only for $\alpha >1$). Might be simpler to just bound all partial sums by $ \sqrt x \sinh a \sqrt x$.

Comment: @Maxim Is it better now?

Comment: I see, thank you, I guess we don't even need an MVT, once we know that $0 \leq \theta_N \leq 1$, it follows that $0 \leq \int \theta_N f \, dx \leq \int f \, dx$ for $f > 0$. For me it's certainly more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$I will assume $a,t,$ are real constants.$$\sin(ax^{1/2})=\Im\exp(i\cdot ax^{1/2})$$

Then consider:

$$\Im\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}\exp(-xt)\exp(i\cdot ax^{1/2})\d x=\Im\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}\exp\left(-t\left(x^{1/2}-i\cdot\frac{a}{2t}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\d x$$

We substitute $x\mapsto x^2$, $\d x\mapsto 2x\d x$, and then shift the variable:

$$2\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\cdot\Im\int_0^\infty x^2\exp\left(-t\left(x-i\cdot\frac{a}{2t}\right)^2\right)\d x=\\\hspace{30pt}2\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\cdot\Im\int_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t}\left(x^2+i\cdot\frac{a}{t}x-\frac{a^2}{4t^2}\right)\exp(-tx^2)\d x\\=2\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\cdot\Im\left[\int_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t} x^2\exp(-tx^2)\d x\\\hspace{35pt}+\color{red}{i\cdot\frac{a}{t}\int_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t}x\exp(-tx^2)\d x}\\\hspace{30pt}-\frac{a^2}{4t^2}\int_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t}\exp(-tx^2)\d x\right]\\=\color{red}{2\frac{a}{t}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\Re\left[-\frac{\exp(-tx^2)}{2t}\right]_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t}}\\\hspace{80pt}+2\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\Im\left[\int_{-ia/2t}^{\infty-ia/2t}\left(x^2-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\exp(-tx^2)\d x\right]\\=2\frac{a}{t}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\Re\left[\frac{\exp(-t(-ia/2t)^2)}{2t}\right]\\\hspace{30pt}+2\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\Im\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(x^2-i\cdot\frac{a}{t}x-\frac{a^2}{2t^2}\right)\exp\left(-tx^2+i\cdot ax+\frac{a^2}{4t}\right)\d x\right]\\=\frac{a}{t^2}-2\frac{a}{t}\int_0^\infty x\exp(-tx^2)\cos(ax)\d x+2\int_0^\infty x^2\sin(ax)\exp(-tx^2)\d x\\\hspace{30pt}-\frac{a^2}{t^2}\int_0^\infty\exp(-tx^2)\sin(ax)\d x$$

Let's evaluate the cosine integral by parts:

$$-2\frac{a}{t}\left[-\frac{\exp(-tx^2)}{2t}\cos(ax)\right]_0^\infty+\frac{a^2}{t^2}\int_0^\infty\exp(-tx^2)\sin(ax)\d x\\\hspace{50pt}=-\frac{a}{t^2}+\frac{a^2}{t^{5/2}}\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^2)\sin\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}x\right)\d x=-\frac{a}{t^2}+\frac{a^2}{t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Now for the middle integral, integrating by parts $x\exp(-tx^2)$ and differentiating $x\sin(ax)$:

$$2\left[-\frac{\exp(-tx^2)}{2t}x\sin(ax)\right]_0^\infty+\frac{1}{t}\int_0^\infty\exp(-tx^2)\sin(ax)\d x+\frac{a}{t}\int_0^\infty\exp(-tx^2)x\cos(ax)\d x$$

But we have already evaluated the latter two integrals, and the first term is zero, so we have:

$$\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)+\frac{a}{2t^2}-\frac{a^2}{2t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Using the [same special function $F$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) on the last integral, we find:

$$-\frac{a^2}{t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Summing all terms:

$$\begin{align}I(t)&=\frac{a^2}{t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)+\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)+\frac{a}{2t^2}-\frac{a^2}{2t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)-\frac{a^2}{t^{5/2}}F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)\\&=\frac{a}{2t^2}+F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)\left[\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}-\frac{a^2}{2t^{5/2}}\right]\end{align}$$

Which is the same as Mathematica’s answer, and more importantly a sketch on Desmos finds the numerical evaluation to be actually correct! Mathematica occasionally gives false answers so it is worth a check...

If you wanted to just see the asymptotics as $t\to\infty$, you could have noticed, without fully calculating, from where I highlighted in red earlier, the $\sim t^{-2}$ relation. The other terms were the imaginary parts of integrals very close to the real axis, which were also being multiplied by an $\exp(1/t^2)$ term, and thus quite negligible. You could expand the $\exp$ to get a more thorough analysis, but for the sake of asymptotes you could have stopped after evaluating the red term.

By the way, don’t worry if Dawson’s integral is new to you, because I myself have never seen this Dawson function $F$ before. I am just told that:

$$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^2)\sin\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}x\right)\d x=F\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Which is all I need to know!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer since it uses the explicit representation in terms of the Dawson function*

$$I=\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}\, e^{-t x}\, \sin \left(a \sqrt{x}\right)\,dx$$

Let $a \sqrt{x}=y$ and $k=\frac t{a^2}$ to make
$$J=2a^3\,I=\frac 1{k^2}+\frac{2k-1}{k^{5/2}}\,F\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{k}}\right) \tag 1$$ Expanded as a series for large values of $k$, we have
$$J=\frac 2{k^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)! }{(2 n+1)!}k^{-n}\tag 2$$ and provided a sufficient large number of terms, this expansion is quite good from the maximum of $(1)$ to $\infty$ (the maximum occurs at $k=0.219873$).

Now, for very small values of $k$, we have
$$J=-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2 n+2)! }{n!}k^{n}$$ which is quite good from $0$ to half the minimum  of $(1)$ which corresponds to $k=0.045636$

Comment: The OP is interested in how to obtain the asymptotics *without* using the explicit representation in terms of $F$.

Comment: @Gary. Edited. By the way, if I may ask, are you an early bird or are you in a non-EU time zone ?

Comment: I am working in Japan nowadays.